# After long period of inactivity Openshift app throws exception when connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, openshift

I have an application on Openshift Tomcat 7 which makes use of MySQL via JPA (Hibernate). Everything works fine except when an action is taken which involves connecting to the database after the longer period of app inactivity (overnight for example).

First attempt to connect to database always fails but subsequent attempt are successful.

This is log output:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 48,764,262 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server wa
s 48,764,262 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
 the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3983) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2596) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5357) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:373) ~[commons-dbcp-eap6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:330) ~[commons-dbcp-eap6.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL disconnects an idle connection after `wait_timeout` seconds, the only sensible way to prevent that behaviour is periodically executing any statement across that connection (`SELECT 1` would do) before the idle timer is up. But besides that you can safely ignore this error if it recovers just fine.

Edit:

I'm not familiar with hibernate, but it seems the answers here might be able to help you with that: [help me avoid connection timeout with JPA, Hibernate & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248372/help-me-avoid-connection-timeout-with-jpa-hibernate-mysql)

Comment: I would be interested how to configure the app so it is not thrown as an error. Something which would not require handling this in code. I do not want the user to get an error in my app because of this.

Comment: As per the update on my answer, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248372/help-me-avoid-connection-timeout-with-jpa-hibernate-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autoReconnect` in the JDBC URL parameter.

The better solution is to catch the exception and check if `java.sql.SQLException.getSQLState()` is equal to `08S01` which means that there were network issues. In that case, try again.